# Retrieve saved ticket details using square connect API

Tags: square-connect

I have been experimenting with square connect API.
Square recently introduced Saved "tickets" which allowed tickets to be printed and modified before actually charging customers.

When ticket is being saved. Is there a way I can retrieved contents of the saved tickets using connect-API?
It does not notify through web hook nor I can retrieve the list anywhere.

Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way to do this through the Connect API.

Comment: I have not tried Fresh KDS, but does that mean the KDS solution also will not provide items in question? Are you aware of a plan squareup may eventually let these details available through api in the future?

Comment: Interestingly Fresh KDS emulates a receipt printer rather than pulling order information through the API. I don't know a lot about it, but they seem to have had success with their implementation.

Comment: Thank you for the info, Troy. I will just wait around until square api actually supports it.